# How to read a matrix into a double** array that is within a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, structure

I have a structure that has double** mat array inside, which is a pointer to a pointer of double values. Suppose the matrix is called m, can I do m.mat[i][j] to put values into the array?

```
struct Matrix {
  size_t row;
  size_t col;
  double** mat;
};
typedef struct Matrix TMatrix;

int readMatrix(TMatrix m) {
    for(int i=0; i<m.row; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; i<m.col; j++)
      {
        if(!scanf("%lg ", (m.mat[i][j])))
           return 0;
      }
    }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images of code.  Edit the question , and put code in the question.

Comment: My bad, first time ever posting on StackOverflow

Comment: @user3704223 No worries; what's most important here is the ability to fix stuff according to feedback! :-) Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't yet!

Comment: A pointer is not an array. Two pointers are even les an array. Read [ask]

Comment: `scanf` needs a pointer not a value. Is `TMatrix` a typo for `Matrix`?

Comment: What "array"?  Where is it created?  Since it's just a pointer to a pointer, there's no there there.

Comment: I know scanf takes a pointer, but isn't array an exception since it is already a pointer?

Comment: *but isn't array an exception since it is array a pointer?*  An array is ***NOT*** a pointer.  An array is a region of memory.  It *has* an address, and in some situations using the array in C code *decays* to that address.  A pointer is a variable that can *hold* an address.  Again:  an array is not a pointer.

Comment: Also, you should pass `m` as a pointer: `int readMatrix(TMatrix* m) ... for(int i=0; i<m->row; i++) ... if( scanf("%lg", &(m->mat[i][j])) != 1)`. I'm a bit curious about how you have actually allocated the memory for that structure.

Comment: This is not yet a [mcve]. Yes you can do this, and no you can't, and this question is a Schrödinger's question until the superposition is resolved and you add code that allocates the matrix structure.

Comment: The structure is created outside any functions, which is static I believe, so I think that's why my instructor did this without passing m as a pointer. So is &(m.mat[I][j]) or &(m->mat[I][j]) a valid way of putting elements to the array?

Comment: Notice: `i<m.col` -> `j<m.col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a 2D array.

However, you can use a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays of double. Even if it isn't a real 2D array, it can in many ways be used in the same way as a real 2D array.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct Matrix {
  size_t row;
  size_t col;
  double **mat;
};
typedef struct Matrix TMatrix;
 
void initMatrix(TMatrix *m, int row, int col) {
    m->row = row;
    m->col = col;
    int i;
    m->mat = malloc(m->row * sizeof(double*));  // allocate array of double pointers
    for (i=0; i<m->row; ++i)
    {
        m->mat[i] = malloc(m->col * sizeof(double));  // allocate array of doubles
    }
}
 
void freeMatrix(TMatrix m) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<m.row; ++i)
    {
        free(m.mat[i]);
    }
    free(m.mat);
}
 
int readMatrix(TMatrix m) {
    for(int i=0; i<m.row; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<m.col; j++)
      {
        if(scanf(" %lg", &m.mat[i][j]) != 1) return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
}
 
 
void printMatrix(TMatrix m) {
    for(int i=0; i<m.row; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<m.col; j++)
      {
        printf("%f ", m.mat[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
 
 
 
int main(void) {
    TMatrix a;
    initMatrix(&a, 2, 3);
    if (!readMatrix(a))
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printMatrix(a);
    freeMatrix(a);
 
    return 0;
}
```

stdin

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

stdout

```
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000
```

Comment: @user3704223 - your `scanf`is wrong. You shouldn't do `if (!scanf(....)` but rather `if (scanf(....) != 1)`

Comment: @user3704223 and instead of `scanf("%lg ` do `scanf(" %lg ` Notice the space before `%lg`

Comment: @user3704223 - I have updated the answer to read from stdin

Comment: Although I find `m->mat = malloc(sizeof *(m->mat) * m->row);` easier to code, review and maintain than this answer line, this is a good reply. Especially for demo-ing with a 2D that does _not_ use the same dimnesions.  2,3 is nicely illustrative.